# how to refer to a menu class in the main clss

Tags: java, android, menu

I have created an Android App and in order to clean up my main class I want to put my code related to the menu option in another class, then in my main class refer to it. I was wondering how I can do that!
Here comes my code:

```
package com.behzadmoradi.farnooshandbehzad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityMenu extends Activity {

// Reference to the menus

public static final int menuExit = 1;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, menuExit, 1, "Exit").setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.star_big_off);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

// Reference to the menu items
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case menuExit :
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Bye", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing concepts here. If you want to clean up your main class you should move other more generic methods to an outside class, but not to an Activity!

If you're using the same menu in many activities, you can also create a generic Activity which declares that methods and then inherit from the other activities.

If that's not your case, and looking at this code, I would leave the code inside your main Activity for code's clarity.